# Error occurs when retrieving timeline for this question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, timeline

Here is the question:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/51812/the-api-sandbox

Here is the API URL:
http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions/51812/timeline?pagesize=100?page=2

Here is the error:

```
code: 500
message: "A generic error has occurred on the server; developers have been notified."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That URL is malformed in a particular way that ASP.NET treats specially (as if it were an attack).

`/1.1/questions/51812/timeline?pagesize=100?page=2`
should be
`/1.1/questions/51812/timeline?pagesize=100&page=2`

Comment: *[Stares at the floor...]* Oops.

Comment: I'm marking this as [status-bydesign] since it appears to be the intended behavior.